# Object.prototype.toString.call fails in SSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

In browser there is a handy way of checking what kind of object you are dealing with by writing following code:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]); // "[object Array]"
```

In xPages SSJS

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
<xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:Object.prototype.toString.call([]);}]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

When I'm doing the same thing in xPages SSJS I'm getting following error message:

> Error calling method 'call(Array)' on an object of type 'function [JavaScript Object]'

Why am I getting this error in xPages SSJS and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: What is the code that you are using? Add it to your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every global object or variable in SSJS is an object of a class defined in Java. The statement

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]);
```

is for JavaScript not for Java. That's why the error. If you wish to find out the class to which the object belongs in SSJS then you can call `.getClass().getName()`.

```
obj.getClass().getName()
```

You can find more information [here](http://naveegator.blogspot.in/2011/12/get-java-class-names-for-variables.html).

Comment: A slightly safer syntax is `typeof obj`, which typically returns the same value as `obj.getClass().getName()`, but does not throw an exception if the current value of `obj` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @TimTripcony: Typically, but not all the time. Sometimes *typeof* just returns *objects* while *getCanonicalName* returns the correct class.